# find whether a string is substring of another string in SML NJ

Tags: string, search, sml

Particularly focus on string manipulation in SML programs because you will process
strings in your task. Your task is to write a function called appears which will take 2 strings in
and decide whether the first string appears within the second one as a substring. Your program
only needs to print the decision; it does not need to show where it is found. So if we call
appears (“abc”, “dsabcbc”);
it will print something like
“abc” appears in “dsabcbc”.
But if we call
appears (“abc”, “dsabbc”);
it will print something like
“abc” does not appear in “dsabbc”

Comment: Please don't just copy your assignment; rather, ask questions about specific things you have difficulties with.

Answer (score 1):

This is a built-in function in [The Standard ML Basis Library](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/string.html#SIG%3aSTRING.isSubstring%3aVAL)   `String.isSubstring` .